# Understanding Cloud Instance per hour

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, cloud, instance

I am getting to be into Cloud Computing, but I am really confused in what it means instance.

In programming you can call an instance whenever you call an object, for a Machine it's a server, but here I can tell it's different, there's where I get confused.

So basically what I need to understand is:
- What is an instance per hour?
- How does it work?
- If I have an app (web app), how can I measure an instance, to calculate the hourly pricing?

Can someone explain this to me as simple as possible? too many tutorials on google and still not getting it

Thanks,
;)

Update: I found this post[What do 'instances' mean in terms of cloud computing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035998/what-do-instances-mean-in-terms-of-cloud-computing?rq=1)
And it's useful because someone answered exactly what I need to understand:

> ```
>   For App Engine it's not a VM; it's a process. – Guido van Rossum Aug 21 '12 at 3:38
> ```

So how can I calculate by process?

Answer (score 5):

The question is a bit vague. My answer is based on the amazon-web-services tag and the phrase "What is an instance per hour".

In the Amazon cloud, you can rent 'EC2' servers. EC2 stands for elastic compute cloud: Amazon's lingo for a virtualized server in the cloud.

An 'instance' is one running EC2 server: one running VM. "Instance per hour" refers to the pricing (as described on https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/). You generally pay-per-use on an hourly base: When the "price per instance per hour" is $1 and you run 1 instance for 4 hours, you pay $4.

When you want to run a web app, you pick an instance type based on memory, cpu capacity and storage type (although you can add storage separately) that's a good fit for your web app, launch the instance and deploy your web app to it.

Comment: Bert, your answer is great. So based on what you said, If I have a simple web app and 1 instance per hour, it does not matter how many hits (http requests) I get? I will still just pay for that instance?

Comment: Yes, you pay per use, which on cloud instances usually equals to running time in hours.